# Smooth transitions using css

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I want to manage hover event just like in the linked fiddle, assuming I don't know how long the

content would be...

My question is: how can I add smooth transitions while hovering?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinny38/fhqxv36q/2)

```css
.news{
 max-width:250px; 
   font-family:Arial, Helvitica, sans-serif;
}

.thumbs {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: -0.25em;
}

.thumbs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  min-height:264px;
}

.thumbs .news-img-container {
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.thumbs li a img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.thumbs li a div.text {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 2px solid #8c1c40;
  margin: -40px 15px 0 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.thumbs li a div.text:hover {
  height: 100%;
  min-height:206px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-top: -160px;
}

.thumbs li a div.text:hover:after {
     background: none;
}


.thumbs li a div.text:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 2em;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,0) 0,#fff 100%);
}

.thumbs li a div.text p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: .9em;
}

h2 {
 color:#8c1c40;
 font-size:1em;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin:0 0 5px 0;
 font-weight:bold;

}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
  <ul class="thumbs">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="news-img-container">
          <img src="http://docteurnature.org/boutique/img/cms/homepage_logo_1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Title h2</h2>
          <p>Long text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget ante libero. Morbi maximus urna id tellus tempus, sit amet volutpat augue venenatis. Pellentesque et fringilla ipsumorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Curabitur eget ante libero. Morbi maximus urna id tellus tempus, sit amet volutpat augue venenatis. Pellentesque et fringilla ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    
     <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="news-img-container">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/65977/pexels-photo-65977-large.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Title h2</h2>
          <p>Shorter text :lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget ante libero. Morbi maximus urna id tellus tempus, sit amet volutpat augue venenatis. Pellentesque et fringilla ipsumorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    
     <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="news-img-container">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33045/lion-wild-africa-african-large.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Title h2</h2>
          <p>even shorter text: lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eget ante libero. Morbi maximus urna id tellus tempus, sit amet volutpat augue venenatis.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    
     <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="news-img-container">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/28201/pexels-photo-28201-large.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Title h2</h2>
          <p>Smallest text: lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Besides, It would be great that the animation launches while hovering the picture...

I'd like to avoid using js, if possible... But if not, well... why not.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here's your updated fiddle with smooth transition on hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/fhqxv36q/4/

All I have done is added some `transition` to `.thumbs li a div.text`. In this particular case, it's `0.3s` for all properties that are changing on hover.

The solution, obviously doesn't take into consideration all the possible transitions and scenarios. It is here to give you an idea of what you need to do.

**EDIT :**
https://jsfiddle.net/fhqxv36q/7/

This takes away the transition effect when you mouse out.

Learn more about transitions here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for such a fast answer. However, how do i prevent transition while moving out with mouse? Transition creates a delay that it quite not right

Comment: do you mean you want transition only when it's expanding but not when it's going away?

Comment: Yes. When going out, it takes the transition delay to come back to initial position, so it's all messy. I guess with no transition while mouse go out, then it should fix it... thanks

Comment: Hi Praveen, thanks for your time on this one. It sure is close to what I want to achieve. Unfortunately, the height property (100%) applied to the hover element pushes the below element as long as the transition occurs. This is quite annoying since the below element since to be to "jumping". I figure I can't avoid it while text is very long, but I'd love to avoid this when it's short enough to fit... Maybe I have it wrong from the beginning. Any idea?

Comment: Add `max-height:264px;` to `.thumbs li`. And consider changing those units to `em` so they scale with the text. You can adjust that on hover: `.thumbs li:hover { max-height: auto; }`

Answer (score 0):

This one should do exactly what you want.

Adding the transition to both the element and its `:hover` state + fixed some other issues it caused.

https://jsfiddle.net/fhqxv36q/5/

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks great. However, the longest text (first block) is truncated. As I said, I don't know the length, so I need to assume it could be very long, and then move down inferiors blocks...